# Inertial Delay in System Verilog

Tags: delay, system-verilog, assign

I'm using inertial delays in system verilog in the following code, mainly to filter glitch

logic y;
wire y_filter;

assign #10us y_filter = y;

my issue is that for the first 10us y_filter is at 'X'.

Is there a simple way to initiliaze the signal at 0?

Thanks,
Alessandro

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `force` statement to force `y_filter` to 0 at time 0, and then `release` it at just after 10us. You will need to make sure that the release does not coincide with any scheduled change from the continuous `assign` statement to prevent another glitch.